# How to create static wrapper around non static methods of each class extended by another class in php

Tags: php, class, oop

I am trying to make a simple php framework for educational purposes. Right now i seem to be stuck on the ORM part. I want to make it so that the user of the framework can create model classes that extend the Model class. this class is must act as some sort of static proxy to the Querybuilder class so that a select query can be preformed statically like this: User::get() this is not possible without a proxy class i think. because the Querybuilder needs to store relations. besides that is get not the only method. i want to do things like: User::where()->get().

before you say you cannot call a non static method statically. yes you can. laravel's equelent orm does it this way so i should be able to as wel right??

right now i have:

a example model for testing:

```php
<?php

namespace App\src\Model;

require_once path('Core/Database/Model.php');

use App\Core\Database\Model;
use App\src\Model\Sales;
use App\src\Model\Product;

class User extends Model
{
    public $table = "user";

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

?>
```

```php
The Model class: 
<?php
namespace App\Core\Database;
echo "Model class loaded";
require_once path('Core/Database/QueryBuilder.php');

use App\Core\Database\QueryBuilder;

class Model extends QueryBuilder
{
    public static function __callStatic($method, $arguments)
    {
        // dd("here) i already checked and this dd doesn't get excecuted meaning its not calling the function __callStatic for some reason
        $instance = new static(static::class);

        if (!method_exists($instance, $method)) {
            throw new \BadMethodCallException("Method {$method} does not exist in class " . get_class($instance));
        }

        return call_user_func_array([$instance, $method], $arguments);
    }
}
```

and the get method of the query builder:

```php
    public function get()
    {
        if (!method_exists($this, 'queryDatabase')) {
            throw new \BadMethodCallException("Method queryDatabase does not exist in class " . get_class($this));
        }

        return $this->queryDatabase();
    }
```

finally my way of calling the function:

```php
dd(User::get());
```

it is not throwing anny of the custom errors. only giving me this one:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Non-static method App\Core\Database\QueryBuilder::get() cannot be called statically in C:\laragon\www\QuickStartPHP\src\Controller\TestController.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\QuickStartPHP\Core\Routing\Router.php(65): App\src\Controller\TestController->index() #1 C:\laragon\www\QuickStartPHP\Core\config.php(12): App\Core\Routing\Router->handleRequest('/test', 'index') #2 C:\laragon\www\QuickStartPHP\index.php(6): require_once('C:\laragon\www\...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\QuickStartPHP\src\Controller\TestController.php on line 28

I don't know why its not calling the magic method even tho it should??

I even asked chat gpt to give me a bare bones example of this consept done right in one singular file.

```php
<?php

class QueryBuilder
{
    public function queryDatabase()
    {
        return "Query executed";
    }
}

class Model extends QueryBuilder
{
    public static function __callStatic($method, $arguments)
    {
        $instance = new static();
        return call_user_func_array([$instance, $method], $arguments);
    }

    public function get()
    {
        return "Data from Model";
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function sales()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(new Sales(), "id", "user_id");
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(new Product(), "id", "user_id")->with("type");
    }
}

class Sales
{
    // Placeholder for Sales class
}

class Product
{
    // Placeholder for Product class
}

// Usage
$user = User::get();
var_dump($user);
```

even after making a brand new project. with this example in it alone, it did not work. it says the get method is not static. which is correct. but i have the proxy in between which should make it static. yet somehow doesn't.

Comment: This approach won't work. `__callStatic` will only be invoked for methods that are not accessible. It will not be invoked for non-static methods invoked from a static context.  You are also not able to declare both a static and non-static function with the same name. Laravel has this concept (calling it "Facades") and it requires the definition of a specific facade class that needs to be used instead of the target class. This appears to be a limitation of the language. You can always separate query builder from model though and this should work (and is better OOP practice).